# Custom shader with SpriteKit & Swift has some difference

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, shader

This is my test shader source code.

```
//Shader/TestShader.fsh
void main() {
vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord).rgba;
gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(1);
gl_FragColor.a = color.a;
}
```

Very simple. It's just for testing.
And for using this shader:

```
//GameScene.swift 
// override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
let sprShader = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
sprShader.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
sprShader.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "Shader/TestShader.fsh")
self.addChild(sprShader)
```

I expected white silhouette of sprite. But it displays white rectangle.
I'm a beginner. Do I have something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answering a VERY old question but you can just add an if statement to the shader

```
vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord).rgba;
if(color.a > 0.1) {
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(1);
}
gl_FragColor.a = color.a;
```

This way only the opaque pixels will be coloured white